# add comment and then something strange shows up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have successfully make the show and create of the comment, however, something strange shows up in the http://localhost:3000/foods/1

```
Comments (9)
crystal d Posted 36 minutes ago.
crystal good Posted about 1 hour ago.
[ #<Comment id: 2, content: "d", user_id: 3, food_id: 1, created_at: "2015-05-03 23:17:30", updated_at: "2015-05-03 23:17:30">, 
  #<Comment id: 1, content: "good", user_id: 3, food_id: 1, created_at: "2015-05-03 23:01:35", updated_at: "2015-05-03 23:01:35">]
```

Does any one know why the [] part shows up?
It shows up so strange and I think I did not add anything = =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're outputting the contents of your comments array in your view template.

If you're using .erb templates, you could try checking if your template contains a stray `<%= comments %>` somewhere.

Editing your question to include your template file would help narrow the cause down.

Comment: I checked and find where I put one more "%="! Thank you so much

Comment: I am sorry I do not know how - - should I just click on the "tick"?